# Replacing an existing hex value with another in an external file with Java

Tags: java, hex

I'm currently trying to make a program that edits the hex values in a 'PAK file' (e.g file.pak). I've currently got the hex values I need to edit but I just don't know how. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Opens file.pak file -> Finds first hex value and replaces it with the second -> Saves file -> Ends

If anyone could help, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Your approach sounds fine. What’s not working?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to do it in Java.

Comment: Unfortunately Joe, this isn’t the place to just say *”how do I do x”*. You should google how to read and write to files in java and actually give it a go. You may surprise yourself. Also, you’ll likely learn much more by making errors than someone just posting an answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll have another look at Google. Thanks for the help anwyays

Comment: Hi again --- I've successfully got it working but I have a major problem. At first I was editing a 3kb text file but now I'm trying to edit a 4.6GB file. I now get the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error. Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/raw/RB04qcWs